# Is it a way to fake the firefox 26.0 as another browser

Tags: networking, network-programming

I noticed that the website recognize the browser by the HTTP header.If the website reject you because of the wrong version of your browser,is it an way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same access issue with you.Finally I found you could easily change the UserAgent for the HTTP header especially in Firefox.You could find the details at the link below.
http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox (which it sounds like you are), try [this Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), which allows you to change your user agent string in your HTTP headers. The user agent string is what web servers use to determine what browser you are using.

If you're looking for a new user agent string to use, check out http://useragentstring.com/. As an example, you can change your user agent string to Chrome/32.0.1667.0.